# Migrating from Ubuntu repository TeX to TeX Live?

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

I installed TeX Live 2013 from CTAN by following the instructions here: [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)

And it's all working very nicely.  However, what I didn't do was purge the original TeX from my Ubuntu 12.04 system.  The command

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep tex
```

shows a vast panoply of installed TeX packages.  Now, suppose I entered:

```
apt-get purge tex*
```

Would that remove just the original TeX packages installed from the Ubuntu repositories, or would it, since my fiddling with `equiv`, kill the new TeXlive as well?

I don't want to experiment, as I now have TeX and friends up and running as I like, and I don't want to have to do it all over again!

Comment: You only need to set up `$PATH` to point to the new installation. Here I have `echo $PATH
/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

Comment: It shouldn't, but I haven't tried in a few years.  However, the middle ground between leaving them and removing them is to remove all the `Apt`-installed files relating to 'fonts' and 'doc': they usually take up the lion's share of disk space.

Comment: @Sigur That's only true if you don't want you use your distro's package manager to install anything with a tex-related dependency. Lots of people will want to install e.g. an editor this way. Hence the stuff with `equiv` (which I think is something like installing a `dummy` package with other Linux distros).

Comment: Yes, I set my `PATH` to include `/opt/texbin` and that's fine.  But in the interests of de-cluttering my system, I'd like to remove all the previous TeX material that isn't part of the new TeXlive install.

Comment: Guys, I think that I'll delete my poor answer to avoid confusion. Sorry for those who wrote comments there.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `.bashrc` and insert

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux:$PATH; export PATH
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
```

Replace mine path to yours.

Or edit `/etc/environment` as suggested by @daleif.

Comment: It is recommended not to set `MANPATH` in general. I'm honestly not sure how this should be handled because putting that in `.bashrc` will likely give quite the wrong result. (Typically, *only* the `texlive` directory will end up in `MANPATH` and this will prevent `man` from finding manpages for everything else.) Or do you know that Ubuntu is an exception on this and sets `MANPATH` explicitly? (A typical setting for `MANPATH` is nothing at all, in which case locations are deduced on-the-fly on the basis of `PATH`. But this does not seem to work for `texlive`.) Also, see my comment above.

Comment: Well, now I am confused I had never had troubles with `man`.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe it tacks it on to the on-the-fly creation rather than replacing it, in that case? Apologies. I'm sure I tried this a couple of years ago and it didn't work at all, but now it seems it works even though `echo $MANPATH` gives nothing. I wonder if it is still recommended not to set it at all in this case? Or if it is just recommended now not to overwrite the system manpath? (So supplementing it for texlive would be fine and I could maybe get `apropos` working for texlive!) You don't need to touch it at all just to use `man` by the way.

Comment: I always use `texdoc <package name>` for example, or `man <command>`, for example.

Comment: Thinking about it, it only really makes sense to supplement it at the system rather than user level unless you are creating a personal database.

Comment: But `man <command>` will work without your touching `MANPATH`. It is enough to change `PATH`. And `texdoc <package name>` is independent, as far as I know. None of that requires changing more than `PATH`. It is only that that is not enough to make `apropos` work, for example, because the supplementary path is not included when the database is updated since that runs as root.

Comment: No, I don't need to change `MANPATH` its basic directories are set in `/etc/manpath.config`, and any other man pages are found on the fly by investigating the `PATH` variable.  I can for example enter `man tlmgr` happily, even though `tlmgr` only exists (on my system) because of the new TeXlive install.

Comment: Please do not recommend setting the PATH variable using bashrc, it is not read if starting an editor via a menu. If the system is Ubuntu, then add the path in /etc/environment

Comment: @daleif, strange. I have `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"` in `/etc/environment` and my editor via menu works fine.

Comment: @Sigur, can it actually compile your documents? i.e. find LaTeX? I've seen many examples where they could not, because the shell the editor use to call LaTeX is not a BASH shell. Which is why I tend to recommend adding it to `/etc/environment` instead

Comment: @daleif why wouldn't it? my setup is the same as Sigur. Of course, I've had it before with your recommendation.

Comment: @doed To test it I just did the following: Installed Ubuntu 13.10 virtually. Installed minimal TL13 (takes 2min). Installed `texmaker` using `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends texmaker`, and added the TL path to `~/.bashrc`. Then I start `texmaker` via the dashboard (or what ever that is called), and it cannot find `pdflatex`. If I start TM from the command line, it starts in an environment where the PATH is set and it knows where `pdflatex` is and it works. But started via the dashboard it does not. *This* is why I do *not* recommand using `.bashrc` to add the PATH.

Comment: @daleif, thank you for your time for testing out the minimal TL, but I was referring to Sigur's comment about the `/etc/environment/`. It follows that my setup, is the same as his. That is, the `/etc/environment` is unchanged. It is worthwhile to point out, that `.bashrc` should not be edited either, as you said. So in that respect, I have to partially agree with you. I can't fully agree, because in the case of Ubuntu or Mint, as long as the PATH is set in `.profile`, everything is good, so it makes no sense whatsoever, to modify `/etc/environment`.

Comment: What makes you believe that Alasdair is running on `i386`?

Comment: Who said anything about `.profile`, might be better, I'm just trying to get rid of the advise to add the path change to bashrc

Comment: @doed, where is sigur saying anything about /etc/environment?

Comment: @daleif, I edited my answer to cite your comment about `/etc/environment`.

Comment: @daleif before you asked him "can it actually compile your documents?" and the answer is yes daleif, it will compile.

Comment: Which my experiment show is not really the case.... Whatever

Comment: Thanks again.  I'm running 64 bits at work; 32 at home.  As an experiment just this morning I removed and purged all TeX/LaTeX from my home system, and installed TeXlive using the script at `https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu`  With regard to setting environment variables, I've never had any problem putting them in my .bashrc; except that of course they are not available to other shells until the next X restart.  In practice that's not a problem except for emacs, and I get round that by starting emacs from the shell, rather than from a desktop icon.

Comment: @daleif I said I agree with you in regards to `bashrc`, not in the `/etc/environment` part.

Comment: @doed, I agree `.profile` will be a better solution if it exist and if it is a single user system. So now we just hae to figure out who is recommended that `.bashrc` stuff in the first place.

Comment: @daleif, just set the `PATH` in each `.profile`, and if the `.profile` does not exist, create it. In the case of Ubuntu or Mint, the latter should not be a concern, since it exists for all the users. I agree with you when you asked who recommended to set it in `.bashrc` in the first place, but couldn't the same be said about modifying `/etc/environment`? That idea has infested the whole stack exchange.

Comment: It depends on the situation, for multiuser, `.profile` is not the solution. And of course `/etc/environment` is not a good idea in general, but it *is* better than `.bashrc` and lets people get on with their systems. Some more research is probably needed, if not then to see for which systems is `.profile` a good solution.